# opencv 3.1 using eclipse (on ubuntu 14.04) imread error

Tags: eclipse, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 in Eclipse Mars ( on ubuntu 14.04). 
Recently I removed opencv 2.4.8 and installed 3.1.0.

AND I added the    opencv_imgcodecs    library to my project, since in OpenCV3 the imread function resides in the imgcodecs module.

When I use 2.4.8 , this simple code from opencv.org worked well,
but now it got errors like 'imread could not be resolved'
imread/imshow/waitkey/namedwindow etc all the same.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
//in opencv 3.1
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

  using namespace cv;

  int main( int argc, char** argv )
   {
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
   {
     printf( "No image data \n" );
    return -1;
   } 

 namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "Display Image", image );

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you include paths for header and your library path are correct ?

Comment: I'm sure I included correctly and I changed nth but reset the computer  2-3 times, it worked. maybe eclipse was the problem. Thx anyway.